# Same logic used in Java doesn't work in Python

Tags: python

I've been practicing a little bit doing the exercises from [this](http://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-conditional-statements-and-loop-exercises.php) website. My question concerns exercise #19 where the following is asked:

[image]

I actually ran the same logic mentioned below in Java and it worked, but I can't understand why it won't work in Python.

```
import os

List = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i in List:

    if i==0 or i==6:
        for j in range(1,5):
            print "*",
        print("")
    if i==3:
        for k in range(1,4):
            print "*",
        print("")
    else:
        print "*",


print("")

os.system("pause")
```

Comment: Euhm `print` enters a new line automatically.

Comment: `range(1,5):` loops 4 times, not 5.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if you add a `,` at the end it won't print a new line

Comment: `print "*"*5` would be better than a loop.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Exactly my thought process. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
for i in range(7):
    if i in [0,6]:
        print('*' * 5)
    elif i == 3:
        print('*' * 4)
    else:
        print('*')
```

- instead of `List = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` use `range(7)`
- you had an error in the `if` statements, you pair them with `if`, `elif`, `else`. The `else` statement in your code was only pairing with the second `if` statement
- printing `print "*",` still omits a space, you can avoid that with doing `'*'*5`
- rewrite `if i==0 or i==6` into `if i in [0,6]`, this is a bit easier to read and easier to extend

Answer (score 2):

The solution for #19 on that website is terrible.
If you're going to keep a static list, keep a static list of number of stars to print per line:

```
num_stars = [5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5]
for num in num_stars:
    print('*' * num)
```

Also worth noting that if you would rather store the input as a string first and print it out, you can use a simple `str.join()` with a list comprehension in it:

```
e = '\n'.join(['*' * num for num in num_stars])
print(e)
```